# how to create an array of multiples of 5 and display it in reverse

Tags: arrays, sorting, reverse, cobol

Make 1D array with appropriate size and input the values with below condition:
1)number below 100
2)which are multiple of 5.
3)Then Print it in reverse order.

I was successful in printing it in ascending order. But need it reversed.
My output:
005
010
015
020
025
030
035
040

Expected:
40
35
30
25
20
15
10
5

Comment: Please [edit] the post to provide the COBOL code used to create the current output. That will help us to explain what changes need to be made.